# Gson return Arraylist of unknown type

Tags: java, json, object, gson

Alright lets say I have 3 Objects.
Object A,
Object B,
and Object C.

And I have 3 json files with each one having only one object type in it.

Can I get the content of the files with only one method?

Something like this:

```
public class jsonConverter {
   public static ArrayList<?> convertFromJson(String path, Object objectToConvertTo) {
    //Get the data in the JSON file
    Object all = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(path));
    //this line would not work 
    return new Gson().fromJson(all.toString(), new TypeToken<List<objectToConvertTo>>() {
    }.getType());
   }
}
```

And then I would be able to get the Content with this:

```
public class main{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<A> arrayListA = JsonConverter.convertFromJson("a.json", new A());

        ArrayList<B> arrayListB = JsonConverter.convertFromJson("b.json", new B());

        ArrayList<C> arrayListC = JsonConverter.convertFromJson("c.json", new C());
     }
}
```

Would something like this be somehow possible? Or would it only work, if I do one method for each Object individualy?

Comment: When you type `//this line would not work` -- did you try it? ... and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, this answer is not exactly what you asked about as it used Jackson instead of GSON, but probably close enough. The `List<A> a = mapper.readValue(aJson, new TypeReference<List<A>>() {});` lines are very close to what you try to do in your `main()` method:

```
@Test
public void testJsonParse() throws Exception {
    String aJson = "[{\"a\":1},{\"a\":2},{\"a\":3}]";
    String bJson = "[{\"b\":\"1\"},{\"b\":\"2\"},{\"b\":\"3\"}]";
    String cJson = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"x\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"y\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"z\"}]";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    List<A> a = mapper.readValue(aJson, new TypeReference<List<A>>() {});
    List<B> b = mapper.readValue(bJson, new TypeReference<List<B>>() {});
    List<C> c = mapper.readValue(cJson, new TypeReference<List<C>>() {});
    System.out.println("a: " + a);
    System.out.println("b: " + b);
    System.out.println("c: " + c);
}

public static class A {
    public int a;
    @Override public String toString() { return "[a=" + a + "]"; }
}

public static class B {
    public String b;
    @Override public String toString() { return "[b=" + b + "]"; }
}

public static class C {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    @Override public String toString() { return "[id=" + id + ",name=" + name + "]"; }
}
```

Output:

```
a: [[a=1], [a=2], [a=3]]
b: [[b=1], [b=2], [b=3]]
c: [[id=1,name=x], [id=2,name=y], [id=3,name=z]]
```

Comment: thx, this is almost better then, what I wanted to do